# Custom Configuration for app.config - collections of sections?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

My head is absolutely pounding badly! I have done this before but not as "in depth" or complex as this and I have tried different ways to make this happen but all has failed.

So, this is the custom XML I want in the app.config:

```
<Profiles> <!--Collection-->
<Profile Name="Live">
   <Components>
    <Component Name="Portal" Type="Web" />
    <Component Name="Comms" Type="Web" />
    <Component Name="Scheduler" Type="WindowsService" ServiceName="LiveScheduler" />
  </Components>
  <Databases>
    <Database Name="Main" Connection="Data Source=.\SQL2008" />
    <Database Name="Staging" Connection="Data Source=SomeSite.co.uk" />
  </Databases>
</Profile>
<Profile Name="Test">
   <Components>
    <Component Name="Portal" Type="Web" />
    <Component Name="Comms" Type="Web" />
    <Component Name="Scheduler" Type="WindowsService" ServiceName="TestScheduler" />
  </Components>
  <Databases>
    <Database Name="Main" Connection="Data Source=.\SQL2008" />
    <Database Name="Staging" Connection="Data Source=Internal" />
  </Databases>
</Profile>
</Profiles>
```

So a collection of Profile with each profile having a collection of sub elements (Components is a collection, then Component is an element)

However I currently have all that EXCEPT for the multiple profiles. I kind of do see the problem but not sure how to "fix" it.

Code:

```
public class Profile : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsRequired=true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return base["Name"] as string;
        }
            set
            {
                base["Name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Components")]
        public ComponentCollection Components
        {
            get { return ((ComponentCollection)(base["Components"])); }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Databases")]
        public DatabaseCollection Databases
        {
            get
            {
                return ((DatabaseCollection)(base["Databases"]));
            }
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Component), AddItemName="Component")] 
    public class ComponentCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {        
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new Component();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((Component)(element)).Name;
        }

        public Component this[int idx]
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BaseGet(idx) as Component;
            }
            set
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(idx) != null)
                {
                    base.BaseRemoveAt(idx);
                }
                this.BaseAdd(idx, value);
            }
        }

        public Component this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BaseGet(key) as Component;
            }
            set
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(key) != null)
                {
                    base.BaseRemove(key);
                }
                this.BaseAdd(this.Count, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Component : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Type", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this["Type"] as string;
            }
            set
            {
                this["Type"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this["Name"] as string;
            }
            set
            {
                this["Name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("ServiceName", IsRequired = false)]
        public string ServiceName
        {
            get
            {
                return this["ServiceName"] as string;
            }
            set
            {
                this["ServiceName"] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Database), AddItemName = "Database")] 
    public class DatabaseCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new Database();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((Database)(element)).Name;
        }


        public Database this[int idx]
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BaseGet(idx) as Database;
            }
            set
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(idx) != null)
                {
                    base.BaseRemoveAt(idx);
                }
                this.BaseAdd(idx, value);
            }
        }

        public Database this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BaseGet(key) as Database;
            }
            set
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(key) != null)
                {
                    base.BaseRemove(key);;
                }

                this.BaseAdd(this.Count, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Database : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this["Name"] as string;
            }
            set
            {
                this["Name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Connection", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return this["Connection"] as string;
            }
            set
            {
                this["Connection"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to have different profiles for different environments, why don't you look at the Slow Cheetah extension for VS which was released this week. Pretty much does what you want: http://www.sadev.co.za/content/appconfig-transformations-community-shines-where-microsoft-drops-ball

Comment: Any info on the problem with the code?

Answer (score 7):

You need to move your configuration section one level higher.

```
public class Profiles : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Profile")]
    public ProfileCollection Profile
    {
        get
        {
            return this["profile"] as ProfileCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a section that I created. You should be able to get yours working by following this:

```
public class ImportConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("importMap")]
    public ImportMapElementCollection ImportMap
    {
        get
        {
            return this["importMap"] as ImportMapElementCollection;
        }
    }
}

public class ImportColumnMapElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("localName", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string LocalName
    {
        get
        {
            return this["localName"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            this["localName"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("sourceName", IsRequired = true)]
    public string SourceName
    {
        get
        {
            return this["sourceName"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            this["sourceName"] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class ImportMapElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public ImportColumnMapElement this[object key]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(key) as ImportColumnMapElement;
        }
    }

    public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap;
        }
    }

    protected override string ElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return "columnMap";
        }
    }

    protected override bool IsElementName(string elementName)
    {
        bool isName = false;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(elementName))
            isName = elementName.Equals("columnMap");
        return isName;
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ImportColumnMapElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ImportColumnMapElement)element).LocalName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing correctly except you need one extra level. Change Profile from a ConfigurationSection to a ConfigurationElement, then make a ConfigurationSection Profiles that contains a collection of Profile items.

This is an excellent case for automated testing, debugging configuration sections without is a royal pain.

Comment: Thankyou all for your replies so far. The Cheetah extension looks interesting.

Comment: woops.. pressed enter too quickly. ssamuel - I believe I tried your approach before but got no where apart from exceptions being thrown saying that it needs to implement the IConfigurationSectionHandler. I will see if I can do this again. But I wonder if its just quicker to serialize/deserialize an object into XML and use that to be honest :-/

Comment: Ugh, what version of the FW are you using? IConfigurationSectionHandler is deprecated after 2.0. If you're still looking, [try this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx). Serialize-to-XML is faster and more intuitive. Writing into configuration is prettier. Depends on where you want to leave the difficulty of maintenance, on the sysadmin or the developer.